# Why is imported typescript function not available in Chrome Debugger

Tags: angular, typescript, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to debug a method that I have imported into an Angular componenent. However some scope peculiarities around typescript are meaning that I cannot access an imported method via the debugger.

The method is the `formatDuration` method from `date-fns`. I want to be able to debug the method directly in the debugger however for some reason the method can't be accessed in the debugger and is always undefined.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { formatDuration } from 'date-fns' // <= method imported

...

export class EntryComponent {

  duration:integer = 1000
  constructor() { }

  get duration():string{

    let duration_str = formatDuration({ seconds: this.duration },
                                      {format: ['hours', 'minutes']}
    )
    // I want to be able to jump in here and use the `formatDuration` method:
    debugger // <= debug statement

    return duration_str
  }
}
```

#### The debugger won't recognise the method when I try to call it

When I run the code above and attempt to call the `formatDuration` method in the console I get an error:

[image]

#### The method IS available to the code that's carrying it

I can't call the method using the debugger however if I remove the debugger statement it is being called successfully. For some reason, it's out of scope of the debugger though ‍♂️

#### Copying the method to a local variable makes it available...

```
get duration():string{

  let duration_str = formatDuration({ seconds: this.duration },
                                    {format: ['hours', 'minutes']}
  )
  // make a copy -------------
  let myVersion:any = formatDuration; 
  // -------------------------
  debugger // <= debug statement
  
  return duration_str
}
```

Running `myVersion` in the console now returns the function as expected:

[image]

### Stackblitz demonstration

[Here's a stackblitz app that shows the problem](https://angular-ivy-mw7rdy.stackblitz.io/). Open your debugger before loading the page and then follow the instructions just before the debug line. [The source code for the Stackblitz page is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mw7rdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

What's happening with scopes such that I can't access the imported method directly?

Comment: What;s the contents of `date-fns` look like?

Comment: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/21088144134ab581ea3a1f77485c645781534198/src/formatDuration/index.js - it's not particular to this method though, it's the same for other methods I import from the same library (as an ECMAScript module)

Comment: Imports will be bundled and accessible not globally, but via the context of your Angular app.  That's how it works with Webpack which is what the Angular CLI uses.

Comment: @Andy-Delosdos is executing the method in the debugger and in a method of the angular app not being in the context of the app? That would make sense if I was simply using the chrome console but surely in a break statement we should be in context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the compiled JS file, because this is what the console will target. This generally depends on the target in your tsconfig.json and/or the packaging system as well. Because you are using angular, the packaging is done with webpack. You can find your `formatDuration` function somewhere here:

```
_date-fns__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.formatDuration
```

The `1` can also be `2` or `0` or `100`, you will have to check the closure in the `Scope` section of the debugger. It's usually in the closure which has as name the typescript file you are debugging. For example:

```
Closure (./src/app/components/entry.component.ts)
```

For example, here you can see the imports from a certain service in my application:

[image: example closure scope]

Obviously, if you use `--prod`, this will all be minified, and will make things a lot harder to trace :)

Comment: It feels sensible that this is a closure issue but I find it hard to wrap my head even around what’s happening with the closures and what the relationship between executing in the runtime (which has no problems) and executing in the debugger (which chokes). Can you shed any light? Thank you

Comment: @PeterNixey you are writing `TypeScript`. This cannot directly run in the browser, and is compiled to most likely an `es5` version, which will work in most browsers. In order to do that, it needs to have a custom module implementation, custom class, custom scopes. That's what's going on right here. However, if you assign it to a local variable, this local variable can be accessed inside the debugger. This: `let myVersion:any = formatDuration; ` is basically compiled to `var myVersion = _date-fns__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.formatDuration;`

Comment: Ahh ok that’s really interesting. I guess it stands to reason but what you’re saying is that the sourcemap that I see in the debugger is not (of course) the source that the browser is seeing (since it’s the original TS). I should expect that the source that the browser is actually executing has very different variable names. This had not occurred to me - thanks for taking the time to explain 

Comment: @PeterNixey you understood well :) and you're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

A bit easier method of using an imported module, to add on Poul Kruijt's answer:

Create a breakpoint in the function that uses that module,
in the devtools in the breakpoints panel, go to Scope, look for your imported module, looks something like that:
[image]

right click the module you want, and select "Store function as global variable".
now you can call it normally, like "temp1.whatever()"